# Error when add WFS

Tags: qgis, wfs

I'm running QGIS 2.4.0-Chugiak on win7 64bit and am getting the following error while trying to add a WFS layer (using the simple Add WFS layer command):

The layer http://copadesvr02.copade.neuquen.gov.ar/geoserver/wfs?request=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=cite:Comunidades_Indigenas&SRSNAME=EPSG:22182 is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map

I managed to add some layers just a while ago but now can't even add those same layers, and I just tried the same WFS service on gvSIG and was successful. Can anyone help me out?

The WFS url is:

http://copadesvr02.copade.neuquen.gov.ar/geoserver/wfs?request=GetCapabilities

Comment: With the correct WFS url (http://copadesvr02.copade.neuquen.gov.ar/geoserver/wfs?), no problem for me

Comment: The problem was that when the url contained the "request=getCapabilities" part, it was included also in the GetFeature requests which QGIS created. Of the two competing requests "GetCapabilies" and "GetFeature" won. I consider this is a QGIS bug. It should check the GetFeature URL from the GetCapabilities response that comes from the server.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! That must be the reason that at first my original url worked but then just stopped working.

Comment: It's not a QGIS bug.  QGIS appends the GetFeature request params to the URL given as the service end point, that's the correct behaviour.   If you send a request to a server with conflicting request operations `REQUEST=GetFeature&` and `request=GetCapabilities&`, it's up to the server how to respond.  The initial connection works because you are sending duplicate operation  requests `request=GetCapabilities&` and `request=GetCapabilities&`...